# Why x00 is usually avoided in salt?

Tags: hash, implementation, salt, database

In .NET Framework, there is a cryptographic Random Number Generator (RNG) provider which enables to generate a cryptographically strong sequence of random bytes. [This provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) contain, among others, two methods:

- `GetBytes` which generates a sequence of random bytes, and
- `GetNonZeroBytes` which does the same thing, except that the generated sequence will contain only nonzero bytes.

In every case I've seen where a salt is generated (for example for PBKDF2), the code similar to this is used, calling always the `GetNonZeroBytes` method:

```
var salt = new byte[128];
using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rng.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
}
```

I'm not sure, but from what I've seen, I believe that zero bytes are avoided in other languages/frameworks too.

Why `GetBytes` is always avoided? What's bad in having `x00` in a salt?

Is there a limitation in one of the popular hashing algorithms (SHA512, PBKDF2, etc.) which prevents using the salt containing `x00`, or the zero bytes are avoided only by fear to having interoperability issues or the issues with the storage of the salt in some third-party database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a limitation of the cryptographic functions, like SHA or PBKDF,  since the zero byte isn't processed any differently.

Since the purpose of a salt is generally to travel alongside a human password, libraries that handle the password as a zero-terminated string might also handle the salt as such a string. Obviously, a `0x00` in the salt would terminate the salt per-maturely when it is processed as a string. If you're interested, you may want to view the code to see where the salts you saw generated actually get used and whether those APIs treat the salt as a string.

In general, there is no universal standard for how to format salt, so the way a salt is processed is left up to the designers of a specification. If you don't know what APIs a salt you generate will be plugged into, the safest strategy is to make the contents all non-zero so it will work with any API that evaluates the salt as a string.

Another (less likely) explanation: In general, there are some standards that require random values that be non-zero. For example, [PKCS v1.5 encryption scheme](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125) (section 7.2.1 step "a") calls for 8 bytes of random padding of nonzero values. In this example the padding value is not a salt, but the existence of such requirements for random data in some specifications may lead a developer to cautiously always generate non-zero random data just to be safe.